# How can I validate the maximum file size is 2 mb per file for multiple files? (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vue-component, vuetify.js, image-uploading

I'm trying to setup a validation rule on Vuetify's `v-file-input` to limit file sizes to 2MB, but the validation incorrectly fails (and the input error appears) when I select files under 2MB.

Excerpt of my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/zYGYXQB?editable=true&editors=101):

```html
<v-file-input
  multiple
  :rules="rules"
  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf"
  placeholder="Pick an avatar"
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  label="Avatar"
></v-file-input>

<script>
  //...
  data: () => ({
    rules: [
      value => !value || value.size < 2000000 || 'Avatar size should be less than 2 MB!',
    ],
  }),
  //...
</script>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is your `v-file-input` accepts multiple files, so the argument of the validation rule is actually an array of `File` object(s) (even if only one file selected). The rule function should look similar to this:

```js
files => !files || !files.some(file => file.size > 2e6) || 'Avatar size should be less than 2 MB!'
```

The rule uses [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the `files` array to determine if any of the file sizes are over `2 * 10^6`. However, since file sizes are in terms of bytes, I recommend comparing to 2[MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) instead (i.e., `2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2_097_152`).

*Demo:*

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    rules: [
      files => !files || !files.some(file => file.size > 2_097_152) || 'Avatar size should be less than 2 MB!'
    ],
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.11/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.2.11/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@4.9.95/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-file-input
      multiple
      :rules="rules"
      accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, application/pdf"
      placeholder="Pick an avatar"
      prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
      label="Avatar"
    ></v-file-input>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I haven't tested it, but something like this should work. In your upload method, loop through the input files and check wether they're all below 2mb:

```
const input = event.target
let files = input.files
//loop through this to check all the file sizes.
const isLt2M = files[0].size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
```